# Print contains data type how to disable

Tags: haskell

using gogol package,
follow example got

```
> exampleGetValue
-- ValueRange' {_vrValues = Just [String "2018/1/1",String "2018/1/2"], _vrRange = Just "'\24037\20316\34920\&1'!A1:1", _vrMajorDimension = Just VRMDRows} 
> exampleGetValue >>= return . view vrValues
-- [String "2018/1/1",String "2018/1/2"]
> mapM_ (print) (exampleGetValue >>= return . view vrValues)
String "2018/1/1"
String "2018/1/2"
```

Why there will be a string of words

How to do I can only show

```
2018/1/1
2018/1/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

```
[String "2018/1/1",String "2018/1/2"]
```

the result of

```
> exampleGetValue >>= return . view vrValues
```

Here the strings you are interested in, like `"2018/1/1"` are contained in another datatype `String`, which has, I assume, an automatically derived show instance, which will print the name of the Data constructor `String`.

You need to unpack the strings somehow to get rid of the printing of the word `String`.

As this is stackoverflow, and we are considered to provide answers, I will give you one possibility now, but before you read it, try to do it yourself:

```
unpackString (String w) = w
mapM_ (print . unpackString) (exampleGetValue >>= return . view vrValues)
```

You have to determine the type signature for `unpackString` yourself, as you didn't provided any types.